# Binding from database using Knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to learn knockout.js and do a look up from a database on a page load. I have everything working except, after the successful database retrieval, the textarea is not being updated with the data from the database.Can someone show me what I'm doing wrong with the binding?

```
<textarea id="taProgramOutcome" data-bind="value: programOutcomeText" rows="12" cols="20"></textarea>


$(function() {
function AppViewModel() {
    this.programOutcomeText = "This is a review"; //initial binding works

    var pageUrl = "/testapp/Service1.asmx";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: pageUrl + "/GetReviews",
        data: "{'disciplineRecordId': '" + 38 + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {         //Database returns records, but the binding does not work.
            this.programOutcomeText = 
ko.observable(result.d[0].disciplineOutcome);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus);
        }
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 potential issues here. `this` in the `success` callback is not the view model. And `programOutcomeText` should be an observable from the start. Try this...

```
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    this.programOutcomeText = ko.observable("This is a review"); //initial binding works

    var pageUrl = "/testapp/Service1.asmx";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: pageUrl + "/GetReviews",
        data: "{'disciplineRecordId': '" + 38 + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {         //Database returns records, but the binding does not work.
            self.programOutcomeText(result.d[0].disciplineOutcome);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked great. I could see I was using a different instance of the viewmodel, but could not figure out how to use the correct instance.

Answer (score 0):

Use `var self = this;` in the viewModel and reference to viewModel fields by `self` in AJAX callbacks. Also, write `self.programOutcomeText = ko.observable("This is a review");` instead of `this.programOutcomeText = "This is a review";` and then `self.programOutcomeText(result.d[0].disciplineOutcome);`.

```
$(function() {
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.programOutcomeText = ko.observable("This is a review");
    var pageUrl = "/testapp/Service1.asmx";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: pageUrl + "/GetReviews",
        data: "{'disciplineRecordId': '" + 38 + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {         
            self.programOutcomeText(result.d[0].disciplineOutcome);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus);
        }
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
});
```